# Collapsing margin on an absolutely positioned div?

Tags: css, css-position

I have 4 div's total:

1 container
1 submenu
1 content
1 sidebar

They are set up as so:

```
<container>
     <submenu></submenu>
     <content></content>
     <sidebar></sidebar>
</container>
```

The container has position:relative and overflow:hidden

submenu and conent has float:left with margins used to position

sidebar is absolutely positioned to the right (float will not work since the subbar affects the layout.

I have images that are listed vertically inside the sidebar but they are cut off by the container. if I float or set position to relative it will contain the sidebar properly. I've tried a clear fix after the side bar but that doesn't work.

This is one of those issues I always see to have problems with. Any suggestions?

-----edit------

```
<div id="content">
    <div id="submenu">
    </div>
    <div id="contentBox">   
    </div>
    <div id="sidebar">
    </div>
</div>

#content
{
    margin: -22px auto 0 auto;
    overflow: hidden;
    padding: 0 10px 10px 10px;
    position: relative;
    text-align: left;
    width: 961px;
}

#submenu
{
    background-color: #001a28;
    border: 5px #008da8 solid;
    float: left;
    margin: -20px 0 0 -10px;
    padding-top: 20px;
    width: 700px;
}

#contentBox 
{
    background-color: #ffffff;
    float: left;
    margin: 10px 0 10px -10px;
    width: 710px;
}

#sidebar
{
    border-left: 5px #008da8 solid;
    border-right: 5px #008da8 solid;
    background-color: #ffffff;
    display: block;
    height: 100%;
    position: relative;
    float: right;
    text-align: center;
    right: 10px;
    top: -10px;
    width: 207px;   
}
```

Comment: could you post a more specific sample code (html/css) or fiddle that reproduces the problem so that we may better answer your question?

Comment: i've messed with my code and I can get the sidebar to be enclosed now, however, I need the side bar to the bottom of the container when <content> is longer than the sidebar. I can get that to happen i should be ok. Seems like I can get one or the other but not both.

Comment: thanks for the update, feel free to post the code if you're stuck

Comment: i posted the html with out content and my css for those sections. that is for the current state. the sidebar will not extend to the bottom of the content div if the contentBox is longer than it.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't found an easy way to make a div 100% of the parent element's height. I've been able to cheat in the past: instead of trying to make the <sidebar> stretch to 100% height, I use a vertical background stretch in the <container> to create a stripe where the sidebar sits, and make the <sidebar> bg-transparent. That way, no matter what the height of the <sidebar> is, there will always be an illusion of it being 100% of the <container>'s height.

Once you have that, just make sure your images aren't being cropped like you described, and it should be the same effect. Though, I can't tell if this will be useful to you without knowing more about what you're trying to accomplish. Hope this helps!